# What is a healthy number of bounties?

Tags: discussion

I am slowly understanding [what the beta-state means](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta). I saw the [Key Performance Indicators](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40709/astronomy) and I am trying to improve the ones in status "okay" by getting involved, e.g. asking or answering questions.

What I did not figure out yet is **how many open bounties at a time are considered healthy.** Personally, I feel that the usal one or two open bounties in parallel here are a bit few - but is there more info on that? I am trying to offer as many bounties as I can afford without loosing privileges. Or shouldn't I?

Comment: For what it's worth, the performance indicators are not really a great guideline for when sites will graduate anymore since SE has been changing how graduations work. Also, they  discourage specifically trying to improve the stats directly, as they find it leads to bad questions and answers. It's better to focus on maintaining quality when you do post about topics that interest you, and if you can bring more people (particularly experts) into the community that always helps too.

Comment: As far as bounties, I don't think there's any problem with offering as many bounties as you desire, but keep in mind the rep cost is steep. You don't get the rep back if no one answers, and you can't award your own answers.

Comment: Oh, and if you want to renew the bounty on a question you already offered it on, you have to pay the next level up in rep points.

Comment: @called2voyage I think it's *double the rep* each time (up to 500), not just the next level. See [this answer](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/889/12102)

Comment: @uhoh Right, thanks for the correction!

Comment: @called2voyage Just to clarify: I am not making up questions *[l'art pour l'art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_for_art%27s_sake)", but I am asking questions on topics I would have in pre-Covid times discussed with physicist and hobby astronomers in person.

Comment: That should be fine. Just want to make sure your expectations are realistic. The site is not going to be pushed to graduation just by asking a lot of questions.

Comment: @called2voyage Understood. I actually intended to ask if others could join me in offering some of their points in order to have some featured questions in the section "bounties". I feel that could motivate more users to participate more actively on astronomy SE.